# X-DWM -- help me fix a bug in C source code

Tags: c, x-dwm

I am using [**dwm**](https://dwm.suckless.org/) *(6.2)* window manager and I found a bug which I would love to solve.

Window manager uses *"master area"* and *"stack area"* where windows are put:

[image]

It is possible to move window at the top of the *"stack area"* to the bottom of the *"master area"* using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>. It is also possible to move windows from the bottom of the *"master area"* back to the top of *"stack area"* using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

Now in this case, if I use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, layout changes and after the key combination there are two windows in the *"master area"*:

[image]

I repeat it again and now there are three windows in the *"master area"*:

[image]

I repeat it yet again and now there are three windows in the *"master area"* which has 100% width:

[image]

If I would at this point decide to return windows from the *"master area"* to the *"stack area"* I would start pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> and windows would imediately return back to the *"stack area"*. This works okay.

But I intentionaly make a mistake and instead press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> again for example **three** more times. It looks like nothing happens...

But now if I try to return windows from the *"master area"* to the *"stack area"* I first need to press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> **three** more times and **nothing will happen**! And then finaly, when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> for the fourth time, window manager will return the first window from the bottom of the *"master area"* to the top of the *"stack area"*.

So this is not well thought out and should be considered a bug...

---

There must be some sort of a counter in the source code which was incremented three more times by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> but it should not increase after all windows are already in the *"master area"*.

---

In `config.def.h` source file ([www](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/config.def.h.html)) there is a part of the code where keys are assigned. And here I can see that when user presses <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> function `incnmaster()` is called and is passed an argument `.i = +1` *(I don't understand this argument)*.

```
static Key keys[] = {
    /* modifier                     key        function        argument */
    ...
    { MODKEY,                       XK_i,      incnmaster,     {.i = +1 } },
    { MODKEY,                       XK_d,      incnmaster,     {.i = -1 } },
    ... 
};
```

`Key` is a structure inside `dwm.c` source file ([www](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/dwm.c.html)):

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int mod;
    KeySym keysym;
    void (*func)(const Arg *);
    const Arg arg;
} Key;
```

Function `incnmaster()` is defined in `dwm.c` source file ([www](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/dwm.c.html)):

```
void
incnmaster(const Arg *arg)
{
    selmon->nmaster = MAX(selmon->nmaster + arg->i, 0);
    arrange(selmon);
}
```

where `arg` is a pointer to `Arg` (`Arg*`) which is a union *(I don't quite understand how to deal with the argument `.i = +1`)*:

```
 typedef union {
    int i;
    unsigned int ui;
    float f;
    const void *v;
 } Arg;
```

`selmon` is a structure `Monitor`:

```
struct Monitor {
    char ltsymbol[16];
    float mfact;
    int nmaster;
    int num;
    int by;               /* bar geometry */
    int mx, my, mw, mh;   /* screen size */
    int wx, wy, ww, wh;   /* window area  */
    unsigned int seltags;
    unsigned int sellt;
    unsigned int tagset[2];
    int showbar;
    int topbar;
    Client *clients;
    Client *sel;
    Client *stack;
    Monitor *next;
    Window barwin;
    const Layout *lt[2];
};
```

`MAX` is defined in a separate source file `util.h` ([www](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/util.h.html)) as:

```
#define MAX(A, B)    ((A) > (B) ? (A) : (B))
```

and function `arrange()` is defined like this:

```
 void
 arrange(Monitor *m)
 {
    if (m)
        showhide(m->stack);
    else for (m = mons; m; m = m->next)
        showhide(m->stack);
    if (m) {
        arrangemon(m);
        restack(m);
    } else for (m = mons; m; m = m->next)
        arrangemon(m);
}
```

I don't think I have to dig any further...

---

Now I think I need to implement some sort of an `if` sentantce in the C code to prevent `selmon->nmaster` to increase too much, but I am a bit confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: `.i = +1` is the same as `.i = 1`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that one. It is a process of "array of union" initialisation like discussed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Answer (score 1):

Why are you holding number of clients when it's linked list? You cant obtain number of clients on demand. Similar code can be found [monocle count patch](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/monocle_count/). If you really have to keep that count yourself (for performance reasons), I would look at any place where is Client list modified by dwm and project that modification to counter.

Structure Client contains pointer to a "next" Client, implementation may depend on whenever you want to use multihead support, but using code similar to Client* c = nexttiled(c->next), where first reference can be obtained from Monitor by calling Client* c = nexttiled(monitor->clients). It you count these in loop that should be enough.

If you want to still keep count yourself, I would find functions within dwm.c working with Client (detach, attach, ...) and find which are modifying list where you can increment/decrement counter based on executed operation.

Comment: Could you be a bit more speciffic? Maybe try to comment actual code so I can understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered before I could figure  this one out myself. Problem is that Suckless team never implemented any kind of mechanism to count a number of opened windows *(they call them clients)*. This is why I added a `int nclients;` member to struct `Monitor`:

```
struct Monitor {
    char ltsymbol[16];
    float mfact;
    int nmaster;
    int nclients;
    int num;
    int by;               /* bar geometry */
    int mx, my, mw, mh;   /* screen size */
    int wx, wy, ww, wh;   /* window area  */
    unsigned int seltags;
    unsigned int sellt;
    unsigned int tagset[2];
    int showbar;
    int topbar;
    Client *clients;
    Client *sel;
    Client *stack;
    Monitor *next;
    Window barwin;
    const Layout *lt[2];
};
```

And then I made sure it is initialized to `0` at boot time by adding `m->nclients = 0;` in `createmon()` function which I guessed is ran at the beginning:

```
Monitor *
createmon(void)
{
    Monitor *m;

    m = ecalloc(1, sizeof(Monitor));
    m->tagset[0] = m->tagset[1] = 1;
    m->mfact = mfact;
    m->nmaster = nmaster;
    m->nclients = 0;
    m->showbar = showbar;
    m->topbar = topbar;
    m->gappx = gappx;
    m->lt[0] = &layouts[0];
    m->lt[1] = &layouts[1 % LENGTH(layouts)];
    strncpy(m->ltsymbol, layouts[0].symbol, sizeof m->ltsymbol);
    return m;
}
```

Then I made sure that my counter `nclients` is increased when new window appears. I added `++selmon->nclients;` and `arrange(selmon);` *(to be able to move clients to stack/master imediately after you close one of them)* statement at the beginning of the `spawn()` function:

```
void
spawn(const Arg *arg)
{
    ++selmon->nclients;
    arrange(selmon);
    if (arg->v == dmenucmd)
        dmenumon[0] = '0' + selmon->num;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        if (dpy)
            close(ConnectionNumber(dpy));
        setsid();
        execvp(((char **)arg->v)[0], (char **)arg->v);
        fprintf(stderr, "dwm: execvp %s", ((char **)arg->v)[0]);
        perror(" failed");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Counter should be decreased when window is closed. This is why I added a `--selmon->nclients;` and `arrange(selmon);` *(to be able to move clients to stack/master imediately after you close one of them)* at the top of the `killclient()` function:

```
void
killclient(const Arg *arg)
{
    --selmon->nclients;
    arrange(selmon);
    if (!selmon->sel)
        return;
    if (!sendevent(selmon->sel->win, wmatom[WMDelete], NoEventMask, wmatom[WMDelete], CurrentTime, 0 , 0, 0)) {
        XGrabServer(dpy);
        XSetErrorHandler(xerrordummy);
        XSetCloseDownMode(dpy, DestroyAll);
        XKillClient(dpy, selmon->sel->win);
        XSync(dpy, False);
        XSetErrorHandler(xerror);
        XUngrabServer(dpy);
    }
}
```

Now that the counter was set up, I could use it to rewrite `incnmaster()` function like this:

```
void
incnmaster(const Arg *arg)
{
    if((arg->i > 0) && (selmon->nmaster < selmon->nclients)){
        ++selmon->nmaster;
    }
    if((arg->i < 0) && (selmon->nmaster > 0)){
        --selmon->nmaster;
    }
    arrange(selmon);

}
```

> Pay attention. My DWM is a bit patched, so some lines might be a bit
>   different than yours, but just stick to the same philosophy and you
>   can fix this.

This solution partialy works. It only fails to work when I:

### A. use `dmenu`

`dmenu` when started can **(a)** open a client or **(b)** do nothing. In case **(a)** everything works as expected, but in case **(b)** `nmaster` and `nclients` become out of sync again.

So for example if I do scenario **(b)** once and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> endless times, I will have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> once and nothing will happen, but if I use it once more one window is moved from master to stack area.

### B. run any kind of windowed application from a terminal

It looks like DWM can't keep track of windows that are run from a terminal and treats them in a wrong way... In this case as well `nmaster` and `nclients` become out of sync.

---

Does anyone know if there is any other function besides `spawn` that is executed when any kind of window is opened?

### This is still not solved!